# Netzke change form header title

Tags: extjs, netzke

```
def preconfigure_record_window(c)
  super  
  c.header = true
  c.width = 600  
  c.draggable = false
  c.title = "New Title"
end
```

In this code I want to change the form title. Whatever I am trying it is displaying the default title `Add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to define it separately for add and edit actions:

```
component :add_window do |c|
    super(c)
    c.title = "New title - add"
    ...
end

component :edit_window do |c|
    super(c)
    c.title = "New title - edit"
    ...
end
```